# How do i convert cpr's get response into a json object?

Tags: c++, rest, nlohmann-json

I was looking for a easy to understand library that make HTTP REST Requests in C++ and then i came across CPR. I was successfully able to get the response from the server but i find it difficult to access the returned JSON object.

API Get Request:

```
auto r = cpr::Get(cpr::Url{ "https://example.net/api/token" },
        cpr::Parameters{ {"username", login}, {"password", password}, 
  {"hwid", "TestChecker"}, {"obt", "1"}});
    r.status_code;                 
    r.header["application/json"];      
    r.text;
```

I tried to pass `r.text` into `nlohmann::json j = r.text;` and access the particular object i wanted like this `string xx = j["token"];`
As expected, it threw an error.

I'd really appreciate it if anyone could tell me how to achieve what i failed to do.

Edit : Added References

CPR : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1244632/Making-HTTP-REST-Request-in-Cplusplus

nlohmann/json : https://github.com/nlohmann/json

Comment: "As expected, it threw an error. " what is the error? did you also try something where you didn not expect an error?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 The error that it threw was : System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException (0x80004005): External component has thrown an exception. The error was thrown from the json.hpp which is a component of nlohmann

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I figured it out(check my answer)  =) thank you for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did play around a bit with the code and finally figured it out. 
Basically what i wanted to do was to convert a "JSON String" into a JSON Object.
I achieved it by using the method `nlohmann::json::parse();`

```
Json j = Json::parse(r.text);
string xx = j["token"];
```